# UICollectionViewDataSource can not execute "fix it", with "Candidate is not a function" in Xcode 9.3.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a base UIViewController and CollectionView

```
class ImageGalleryViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {
        didSet {
            collectionView.dataSource = self
        }
    }
}
```

When I add following code, Xcode warning `Type 'ImageGalleryViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'`, and i know what to do

```
extension ImageGalleryViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
}
```

So I click the exclamation mark, then click fix it, but I recieve anothor two gray warning besides `@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView! {`

```
1. Candidate is not a function
2. Candidate is not a function
```

if i completed code for UICollectionViewDataSource manually, all warnings and errors disappeared.

Buy why the "Fix it" failed?

My Xcode Version is 9.3.1

Comment: Update: I lose the function at all, anytime i can not see fix it button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I found the reason.

I created several other Class, such as class MyNumber: Equatable {} , All is right, I can see the two following Red Errors:

```
Type ‘MyNumber' does not conform to protocol ‘Equatable'
Do you want to add protocol stubs? [Fix]
```

When I click Fix it, respected code is coming.

Then I Create a new blank project to test UICollectionViewDataSource, and I found the point is : DO NOT name Collection View Outlet by "collectionView" in the ViewController, any other name is OK, but not "collectionView"

Following code is OK

```
@IBOutlet weak var galleryCollectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Not OK, will cause protocol stubs fix function failed

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

Connect the `datasource` (and `delegation` if needed) in Interface Builder or if you really want to do it in code, do it in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: certainly i can do it in interface builder, but why it's failed in code

Comment: @vadian any reason why? I commonly do this with custom (pre fetch)data sources/delegates... I could see just to keep the code clean but can't think of anything else and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.